# GNU Make and archives

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to make a project with GNU make on Linux that uses some libraries created from sources in subdirectories. Here is a stripped-down Make file subset:

```
TARGETS := a b c
VPATH = aa:bb:cc
LDFLAGS += -Laa -laa -Lbb -lbb -Lcc -lcc

all: $(TARGETS)
$(TARGETS): libaa.a libbb.a libcc.a
libaa.a:
  $(MAKE) -C aa $@
libbb.a:
  $(MAKE) -C bb $@
libcc.a:
  $(MAKE) -C cc $@
a: a.cpp 
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
b: b.cpp qq.o
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
c: c.cpp rr.o
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
```

The problem I'm encountering is that when first run, the libraries are created successfully but the programs are not (because it uses the names of the libraries in the command to compile the programs, and they are in subdirectories, and VPATH didn't know that when make was first executed), and I get an error similar to:

```
g++: error: libaa.a: No such file or directory
```

But when I run it again, VPATH kicks in and gets the correct path for the libraries. The names of the libraries are not even really needed when the program compiles because the -L and -l directives will find them correctly. How do I get rid of these names in the compile command, letting the -L and -l directives do their job, yet still have each program depend on the libraries?

Comment: Note: recursive make is considered harmful. There is a paper by this name explaining the dangers. By removing recursion you can reduce complexity, and increase speed. You can still use `include` to split make into several files.

Comment: Note: you have twice repeated a rule 3 times. Using patterns will simplify your make.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor This is not my real make file. It merely illustrates that I have multiple libraries built in multiple directories. Patterns would not work on my real codebase. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g++: error: libaa.a: No such file or directory
```

This error happens because `$^` automatic variable is a list of file paths to the targets, which gets passed to `g++`. `libaa.a` resides in another directory, hence, the error.

---

One solution is to use relative paths to the static libraries. In this case, no `VPATH`, `-L` or `-l` options are needed. The linker finds `.a` files using their paths, rather than searching default and `-L` library directories for matching libraries specified with `-l` option:

```
TARGETS := a b c
all: $(TARGETS)

$(TARGETS): aa/libaa.a bb/libbb.a cc/libcc.a
# $^ includes the paths to archives
a: a.cpp 
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
b: b.cpp qq.o
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
c: c.cpp rr.o
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

aa/libaa.a:
  $(MAKE) -C aa $@
bb/libbb.a:
  $(MAKE) -C bb $@
cc/libcc.a:
  $(MAKE) -C cc $@
```